# With Gauss-Jordan there is only one Polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a problem to find the answer to this:
$x₁,x₂,x₃ \in \mathbb{R}$ where $x₁<x₂<x_3$ and $y₁,y₂,y₃ \in \mathbb{R}$. With Gauss-Jordan I would like to show that exist only one Polynome $p \in \mathbb{R[x]_2}$ where $p(x_i)=y_i$ with $i=1,2,3$.
I thought to do like this:
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix} 
    a_{11} & a_{12}&a_{13} \\
    a_{21} & a_{22}&a_{23} \\
    a_{31} & a_{32}&a_{33}
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{pmatrix} 
   x_1 \\
   x₂ \\
   x_3
\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix} 
   y_1 \\
   y₂ \\
   y_3
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
And and I can find the system:
\begin{cases}
  a_{11}x_1 + a_{12}x_2 +a_{13}x_3 &= y_1 \\
       a_{21}x_1 + a_{22}x_2+a_{23}x_3 &= y_2 \\
  a_{31}x₁+a_{32}x_2+a_{33}x_3 &= y_3 
\end{cases}
but now I don't know how to show that there is only one polynom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: write down your polynomial as $p(x)=Ax^2+Bx+C$ so that
$$p(x_i)=Ax_1^2+Bx_1+C=y_1$$
$$p(x_2)=Ax_2^2+Bx_2+C=y_2$$
$$p(x_3)=Ax_3^2+Bx_3+C=y_3$$
holds. This gives you a linear system for $A, B, C$. Do you recognize the form of the matrix? You only need to show that the matrix is invertible in order to know that the system has exactly one solution.

Comment: But how can I proof that this matrix is invertible? Because the property is AB=BA=E, and we have a matrix like $\begin{bmatrix} 
    A & B&C \\
    A & B&C \\
   A & B&C 
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: The matrix is $\begin{pmatrix} x_1^2 & x_1 & 1 \\ x_2^2 & x_2 & 1 \\ x_3^2 & x_3 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$. Note that the $x_i$ are given values, not unknowns. The unknowns are $A$, $B$, $C$.
Now how do you prove that a $3\times 3$ matrix is invertible? It might be a recognizable matrix.